# finding the middle index of a substring when there are duplicates in the string

Tags: java, string, oop, substring

I was working on a Java coding problem and encountered the following issue.

**Problem:** 
Given a string, does "xyz" appear in the middle of the string? To define middle, we'll say that the number of chars to the left and right of the "xyz" must differ by at most one

```
xyzMiddle("AAxyzBB") → true
xyzMiddle("AxyzBBB") → false
```

**My Code**:

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  boolean result=false;
  if(str.length()<3)result=false;
  if(str.length()==3 && str.equals("xyz"))result=true;
  for(int j=0;j<str.length()-3;j++){
    if(str.substring(j,j+3).equals("xyz")){
       String rightSide=str.substring(j+3,str.length());
       int rightLength=rightSide.length();
       String leftSide=str.substring(0,j);
       int leftLength=leftSide.length();
       int diff=Math.abs(rightLength-leftLength);
       if(diff>=0 && diff<=1)result=true;
       else result=false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Output I am getting:**
Running for most of the test cases but failing for certain edge cases involving more than once occurence of "xyz" in the string

Example:

```
xyzMiddle("xyzxyzAxyzBxyzxyz")
```

My present method is taking the "xyz" starting at the index 0. I understood the problem. I want a solution where the condition is using only string manipulation functions.

NOTE: I need to solve this using string manipulations like substrings. I am not considering using list, stringbuffer/builder etc. Would appreciate answers which can build up on my code.

Comment: Why do you use `substring(a, b)`, and take the length of the resulting string? The length is simply `b-a`.

Comment: appreciate the answers. Thanks all, I was able to break through my mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop at all, because you only want to check if `xyz` is in the middle.

The string is of the form

```
prefix + "xyz" + suffix
```

The content of the prefix and suffix is irrelevant; the only thing that matters is they differ in length by at most 1.

Depending on the length of the string (and assuming it is at least 3):

- Prefix and suffix must have the same length if the (string's length - the length of `xyz`) is even. In this case:

  ```
  int prefixLen = (str.length()-3)/2;
  result = str.substring(prefixLen, prefixLen+3).equals("xyz");
  ```
- Otherwise, prefix and suffix differ in length by 1. In this case:

  ```
  int minPrefixLen = (str.length()-3)/2;
  int maxPrefixLen = minPrefixLen+1;
  result = str.substring(minPrefixLen, minPrefixLen+3).equals("xyz") || str.substring(maxPrefixLen, maxPrefixLen+3).equals("xyz");
  ```

In fact, you don't even need the substring here. You can do it with `str.regionMatches` instead, and avoid creating the substrings, e.g. for the first case:

```
result = str.regionMatches(prefixLen, "xyz", 0, 3);
```

Comment: str.substring(prefixLen prefixLen+3) : what does this line do?

Comment: Typo, should have had a comma in it.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy solution:

1. Use [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) to split the string.
   Specifically, `splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens`.
2. *Think about the problem.
   Specifically, if the token is in the middle of the string then there must be an even number of tokens returned by the split call (see step 1 above).
   Zero counts as an even number here.*
3. If the number of tokens is even, add the lengths of the first group (first half of the tokens) and compare it to the lengths of the second group.
   Pay attention to details,
   an empty token indicates an occurrence of the token itself.
   You can count this as zero length, count as the length of the token, or count it as literally any number as long as you always count it as the same number.
4. if (lengthFirstHalf == lengthSecondHalf) token is in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Managing your code, I left unchanged the cases `str.lengt<3` and `str.lengt==3`.
Taking inspiration from @Andy's answer, I considered the pattern

> prefix+'xyz'+suffix

and, while looking for matches I controlled also if they respect the rule *IsMiddle*, as you defined it. If a match that respect the rule is found, the loop breaks and return a success, else the loop continue.

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
      boolean result=false;
      if(str.length()<3)
              result=false;
      else if(str.length()==3 && str.equals("xyz"))
              result=true;
      else{
          int preLen=-1;   
          int sufLen=-2;
          int k=0;
          while(k<str.lenght){
              if(str.indexOf('xyz',k)!=-1){
                count++;
                k=str.indexOf('xyz',k);
                //check if match is in the middle
                preLen=str.substring(0,k).lenght;
                sufLen=str.substring(k+3,str.lenght-1).lenght;
                if(preLen==sufLen || preLen==sufLen-1 || preLen==sufLen+1){
                   result=true;
                   k=str.length; //breaks the while loop
                }
                else
                   result=false;
              }
              else
                k++;
          }


        }
      return result;
    }
```